# Create a new variable based on three variables in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable called `N1` based on three existing variables (`resp`, `exp.1`, `exp.2`) in R.

```
df <- data.frame(
                 resp = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7 ),
                 exp.1 = c(0, 0.24, 1, 1.5, 0, 0.4),
                 exp.2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.2)
)
```

```
df   resp  exp.1   exp.2
1   1      0        1
2   2      0.24     1
3   2      1        0
4   4      1.5      0
5   5      0        0.3
6   7      0.4      0.2
```

I want to make a new variable `N1` like this:
when `resp` >4, extracting values from `exp.1`
when `resp` <4, extracting values from `exp.2`
when `resp` == 4, making it missing values.

The desired outcome is:

```
df   resp  exp.1   exp.2   N1
1   1      0        1      1
2   2      0.24     1      1
3   4      1        0      NA
4   3      1.5      0      0
5   5      0        0.3    0
6   7      0.4      0.2    0.4
```

I tried my best using `mutate()` or `car::recode()` but it does not work. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Using `case_when`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(N1 = case_when(
    resp>4 ~ exp.1,
    resp<4 ~ exp.2,
    resp == 5 ~ NA_real_
  ))

  resp exp.1 exp.2  N1
1    1  0.00   1.0 1.0
2    2  0.24   1.0 1.0
3    4  1.00   0.0  NA
4    3  1.50   0.0 0.0
5    5  0.00   0.3 0.0
6    7  0.40   0.2 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Using `case_when()`, as given in the solution above, might be better.

```r
library(dplyr)
# #Data
df <- data.frame(
    resp = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7 ),
    exp.1 = c(0, 0.24, 1, 1.5, 0, 0.4),
    exp.2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.2)
)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(N1 = if (resp >4) {
                exp.1
              } else if (resp <4) {
                exp.2
              } else if (resp ==4) {
                NA
              } else {
                NA
              }
        )
## A tibble: 6 x 4
## Rowwise: 
#   resp exp.1 exp.2    N1
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  0      1     1  
#2     2  0.24   1     1  
#3     4  1      0    NA  
#4     3  1.5    0     0  
#5     5  0      0.3   0  
#6     7  0.4    0.2   0.4
```

Comment: `case_when`, as suggested by @Park, is more feasible in this case, as it allows you to nest multiple `if`-statements in a cleaner fashion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I was unaware of that till now :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried 'case_when' but the new variable created is NULL. Also, I tried 'if' and 'else if' fucntion but resulting in this error message. '''Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `N1`.
ℹ `pro.exp = if (...) NULL`.
x missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
ℹ The error occurred in row 82.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 7. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 8. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))'''   Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: @noone : I don't understand. Are you saying, my code is throwing this Error? If Yes, Then please show the output of `str(df)`  for actual dataset on which you are trying to add another column.

Comment: Fixed it! Now it works... There was a scratch in my dataset (since it was too big). Sorry for the confusion-- and thanks for writing such a clear code!